# Why does creating a TagLib::FileRef only takes time the first time?

Tags: c++, qt, taglib

As part of a music player I am developing with C++/Qt, I am scanning all audio files with taglib to get the metadata for the database.

I noticed something interesting.
The first time after a restart, it takes about 100ms and 500ms on my system to create a TagLib::FileRef object. When I use the same file again to create a TagLib::FileRef it takes 0ms, even after I restart the musicplayer.

Here is the function I am using to test that:

```
bool suffixCheck(const QString &val)
{
    if (val.endsWith(".mp3")) {
        return true;
    }

    if (val.endsWith(".m4a")) {
        return true;
    }

    if (val.endsWith(".ogg")) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void doTaglibThing(const QString &path)
{
    if (suffixCheck(path)) {
        QElapsedTimer timer;
        timer.start();
        TagLib::FileRef f(path.toUtf8().data(),
                          true,
                          TagLib::AudioProperties::Accurate);
        Q_UNUSED(f);
        qDebug() << "End taglibThing" << timer.elapsed();
    }
}
```

Why is this? I assume that taglib somehow "remembers" the objects. How can I make it so that taglib doesn't remember and always actually has to read the file.

I want to optimize the library scanning function and I don't always want to restart the whole system to check how changes to the code impact the first-run scan.

Comment: I don't think it's magic in Taglib here, it's probably just that the file data is still in disk cache and thus only RAM access but no disk access is necessary after the first access.

Comment: Most likely just a static variable taking time to be initialized

Comment: @jpo38 r-mean said it's still fast after application restart

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld thank you, clearing the disk cache did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Frank Osterfeld, the file data was still in disk cache.

Clearing the disk cache with

```
sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

makes taglib re-read the file from the disk again.